# Send 3 space minus a ring onto the circle

Tags: general-topology, geometry, continuity

Here's a topology problem I'm having trouble solving. I'm sure it's something simple.

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be $\{z=0; x^2 + y^2 =1\}$. Show that
>   there is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S$ onto
>   the circle.

I can go more into the things I've tried if you like. I think I'm just missing something dumb, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your guiding intuition should be that we can't create a map such that its restriction to $\Bbb R^2 \setminus S$ is onto.

Try to make a function that depends only on the $z$-coordinate (so that the restriction to $\Bbb R^2 \setminus S$ is a constant function).

Comment: How could we rigorously show we can't create a map of the type you mention?

Comment: Ah, I guess we can't... I made a mistake there.  What I was really thinking is that there's no continuous onto map from the unit disk to the circle.